# issue with docker container with .net core 3.1 web app

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dockerfile

I have created an MVC project with .net core 3.1 and enabled docker support, so I have the docker file in the project.

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise and Docker desktop community client for windows and it is running as a Windows container.

When I compile the project from the Visual Studio 2019, it creates the image and then the container, and by running: "docker container ls" I see it running.

I had to inspect the container to see the IP of the container and be able to run the page from the URL coming from the container. So having the IP of the container (172.24.121.233), I put this in the browser: http://172.24.121.233:80 and I see my web page. But the issue is after I stop running the MVC app from Visual Studio this URL does not work anymore?

I was expecting it to run independently? Any help to solve this issue and get the container running independently from Visual Studio?

Thanks

Comment: Simply build/run your container from command line using standard docker tools: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/

Comment: tried that, and did work, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course, you can run the docker container again: first, run `docker ps -a` (or if you don't run the container at all, `docker images -a`), find your container (or image) and run it by the command `docker run <IMAGE_NAME>`

Two hints:

- if you want to detach from the container after running it, use `-d` switch
- if you want to access port 80 of your image without finding the container IP, use `-p 180:80` and use your port 180 of host machine

Comment: Thanks. It is not working anyway ->  "docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webappctr2 sampleappimg". Apart from that, I pinging the IP of the container and I get a timeout, any ideas? why is it so difficult?. The container says up and running.

Comment: tried also as you suggested: docker run -d -p 180:80 --name webappctr3 sampleappimg, I see the container up, but after inspecting the container to get the IP, and I ping it, it is not responding.

Comment: why do you need the IP? if you mapped the ports with `-p 180:80` you can see your application in `http://localhost:180`

Comment: wow, amazing, that worked! thanks a lot! so this worked fine: http://localhost:180/